# Kext superclass not starting - IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00::start() doesn't return

Tags: macos, device-driver, kernel-extension

I am writing a SCSI pass-though device driver sub-classed from `IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00` for a USB-attached mass storage device. The device intercepts some vendor-specific SCSI commands in the firmware and replies appropriately, as well as responding to "normal" SCSI commands.

I have implemented a drive much in the style of [this Wagerlabs code](http://wagerlabs.com/blog/2008/02/04/writing-a-mac-osx-usb-device-driver-that-implements-scsi-pass-through/).

The `init()` and `probe()` methods are basically empty, just doing some logging and calling the repetitive super-class functions. These appear to be working correctly (the logs appear as expected and the driver is assigned to the device when it is plugged in). However, when the driver's `start()` method is called, the super-class' `start()` is called first but does not return until the device is unplugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that the device was not properly initialising the attached disks and therefore was not allowing the `start()` method, which was passed up the classes to `IOSCSIProtocolInterface::start()` to properly communicate with the device, hanging the startup until the device was physically unplugged.